# Cannot compile java code [Unicode Byte Order Mark 65279]

Tags: command-line, java, programming, gedit

I wrote a simple Java program with the `gedit` text editor.

```
public class Example{
    public static void  main (String args [])
    {
    System.out.println("hi yaar");
    }
}
```

When I tried to compile it on the terminal, it threw out a lot of errors, and I don't know why. It's supposed to work.

Here are the errors:

```
arvind@arvind-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/Documents$ javac Example.java

Example.java:1: error: illegal character: \65279

public class Example{
       ^

Example.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected

public class Example{
          ^
Example.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected

public static void  main (String args [])
          ^

Example.java:5: error: class, interface, or enum expected

}
^

4 errors
```

I have tried to search on a lot of forums, but did not find an answer. How can I solve this?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: m using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Hi Arvind, can you please format your question? If needed, read the FAQ.

Comment: @arvind If your code have syntax problem means that it's not related with Ubuntu, in such case it is off-topic and it should be moved to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) site.

Comment: no code syntax problem here...

Comment: Did you switch the format to Java Code in gedit?

Comment: yeah...i did save it as Example.java

Answer (score 2):

`illegal character: \65279`, this sounds like an encoding problem.

1. Check the encoding of your source code file: `file -bi Example.java`
2. Use the encoding as option for `javac`, e.g. `javac -encoding UTF-8 Example.java`

Also keep in mind that decimal 65279 is hex FEFF.
Which is known as the Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM). In UTF-8 is this information  misleading, because it is always an 8-bit and not a 16-bit stream.

`javac` can't handle this. So use another editor, which is not doing such a cruft.

**BTW:** Use better an IDE like *eclipse* or *netbeans* for programming in java. This may protect you from some subtly problems (e.g. the encoding of property files has to be latin-1).

Comment: @Schmitt i tried it...still comes up with same errors

Comment: netbeans on linux...how to get it?

Comment: im well versed with the java programming in windows...tried to do the same in ubuntu 12.10 thru terminal....stuck badly

Comment: encoding of your source code file    text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: any suggestions for a text editor??

Comment: @arvind This is not an allowed question. It may be the start of a flame war. I say just a word `emacs` and taking shelter :-)

Comment: Note: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length character encoding, so "because it is always an 8-bit and not a 16-bit stream" isn't really correct. In UTF-8, a character may be between 1 and 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This extra character will be usually at start of the first word of the doc.

In my code,  all the words in the doc are stored in the array word[].

We can ignore that character using:

```
   if((int)word[0].charAt(0)==65279)
         word[0]=word[0].substring(1);
```

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, there is no problem compiling the code. You manually write the code in (notepad ,notepad++), use encoding encode in UTF-8, and then compile the code.

Otherwise use:

```
javac -encoding UTF8 yourclassname.java
```